# pyOCCT vs PythonOCC for new project (2020)

Tags: opencascade, pythonocc

I am starting a new project with some 3D CAD objects to be generated from a specific domain data. I can code it with c++ using OpenCascade but I prefer to use Python if possible. There are two popular occ python bindings: [pyOCCT](https://github.com/trelau/pyOCCT) and [PythonOCC](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core), both projects are active and up to date with occ 7.4 but it will be great to have an advice from someone who knows both. As pyOCCT is a newer project, I suppose it solves something that PythonOCC does not, but it is not clear what was the motivation to create a new binding. I will need some **web rendering** support, apparently PythonOCC already support web rendering.

Answer (score 7):

A little background: I was working on a project and using pythonocc. It's a great project, but at the time was stuck on OCE (OpenCASCADE Community Edition) v6 and OpenCASCADE (official) had since released v7+ with a lot of performance improvements. I attempted to update pythonocc wrappers to v7+ but with 7+ they made much more use of c++ templates and I couldn't get a handle on how to do this in SWIG. When I tried doing this with pybind11 it seemed like a more natural fit (and I was able to get it working). So, I started pyOCCT to wrap OCCT 7+ using pybind11.

Since then, pythonocc has updated its wrapper process and now targets OCCT, so you can't go wrong with either if you are just looking for access to OCCT in Python. Pythonocc has a larger user base so you will likely find more people to collaborate with.

I've tried to keep up with [SMESH](https://github.com/trelau/SMESH) and recently started up a [pySMESH](https://github.com/trelau/pySMESH) project for CAE applications if that is relevant to your work. That is only compatible with pyOCCT. Though again, with some extra effort you could probably write SWIG wrappers for SMESH instead of pybind11 ones if you really wanted to, making it compatible with pythonocc.

Answer (score 2):

**Neither.** Use [CadQuery's OCP](https://github.com/CadQuery/OCP) instead, because OCP is the *only* OCCT Python wrapper to internally use a [sane clang-based binding generator](https://github.com/CadQuery/pywrap). OCP is thus roughly analogous to  [PySide2](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/Shiboken), which also internally uses a [sane clang-based binding generator](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/Shiboken) to generate its Python bindings.

Meanwhile, pyOCCT uses the [hand-rolled `pybind11` binding generator that requires C[++] headers to be modified with `pybind11`-specific macros](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11). Since `pybind11` does *not* leverage clang, neither does pyOCCT. Bizarrely, there's actually a [downstream binding generator ambiguously named "Binder"](https://github.com/RosettaCommons/binder) that does leverage both `pybind11` and clang. Of course, pyOCCT doesn't use Binder.

All else being equal, what you're usually looking for when choosing between higher-level language bindings to lower-level language frameworks is whether those bindings use clang or not. Prefer clang-based bindings to ad-hoc bindings that try (and usually fail) to parse C[++] with hand-rolled lexers and parsers. C[++] is a dark pit of lexical, syntactic, and semantic edge cases you *never* want to parse with non-standard toolchains.

Trust clang. Distrust everything *not* clang. This is the way.

Comment: pyOCCT is not developed to be a general code generator like pywrap, nevertheless it is based on clang https://github.com/trelau/pyOCCT_binder/tree/50853bc763f53e965dc1ade8c75f5a4a017a07ca

Answer (score 1):

pyOCCT is based on pybind11 template library which is simple and powerful. PythonOCC is based on SWIG which is rather complicated. I have tried both, pyOCCT looks more attractive and perspective, especially if you need to add your own wrappers for some purpose. However, I do not use web rendering at all.